# convert sql to plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hello I have three codes in sql and you know you advice on how to rewrite them in pl / sql.I can not find an answer or program to transform

thanks for help

1

```
SELECT PATIENT.NAME ,
PATIENT.NAME_OF_DOCTOR,
PATIENT.ROOM_NUMBER
FROM PATIENT ;
```

2

```
SELECT WING.NAME ,
WING.SISTER_ON_WING,
WING.NURSES
FROM WING
oRDER BY WING.NAME,
WINGSISTER_ON_WING,
WING.NURSES;
```

3

```
SELECT COUNT (*) ,
CASE radiation_theraphy
WHEN '1' then 'Attendance'
WHEN '0' then 'Absence'
wHEN null then 'Null'
END radiation_theraphy
FROM patient
GROUP BY radiation_theraphy;
```

Comment: PLSQL is SQL. Those queries are quite basic without anything that would differ between implementations, so they should work without changes. Have you tried them?

Comment: yes its working but they need from me block pl/sql not standard sql

Comment: In order to put SQL in PL/SQL you need some sort of reason for doing so... are you returning the result set in a cursor? Are you going to use the results for some sort of calculation? Do you have any conditions on these at all? The basic answer on "how" to do is is [covered in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345), but copying and pasting some answer here that says that won't help you without context.

Comment: Why do you want this as a stored procedure? Can't you just use the SQL statements?

Answer (score 0):

With SELECT clause you retrieve data from database. If you need to handle it in your PLSQL code, you have to put result into variable. For that you can use simple SELECT ... INTO clause (which works only for select always returning one row) or cursor together with looping over selected data, like this:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_patient IS
    SELECT COUNT (*) ,
           CASE radiation_theraphy
             WHEN '1' then 'Attendance'
             WHEN '0' then 'Absence'
             wHEN null then 'Null'
           END radiation_theraphy
      FROM patient
      GROUP BY radiation_theraphy;
BEGIN
  for r in c_patient loop
    -- do something. you access values by r.<selected_column_name>,
    -- for example r.radiation_therapy
  end loop;
END;
```